# Linux replace remove chars from string and save to var

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci

This is my gitlab-ci.yml file. Mainly it just executes script lines

```
    before_script:
  - export RELEASE=${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG}
```

In ${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG} can be feature/myproduct-1

but i want to remove the "/" and "-" chars

I tried it in a simple linux console like so:

```
echo "feature/myproduct-1" | tr -d /-
```

And it worked. But i just cant get it working inside the yml

So what i want that the value that is parsed to RELEASE is free of "-" and "/" chars.

UPDATE: this is halfway what i want. Now i need to remove the "/" and i am done

```
RELEASE='feature/sendis-6'
new=$(echo $RELEASE | sed 's/-//g')
echo $new
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing

```
before_script:
  - RELEASE=$(echo $CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG | sed "s/[^[[:alnum:]]//g")
```